# Extension for VisualStudio that switches from .tt file to the generated .cs file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm using T4 templates in my project. Every .tt file generates a .cs file. Is there a plugin/extension that allows for a quick and easy switch between the template file and the generated file? It can be a button, it can be a keyboard shortcut - anything really!